# Recurring Payment Issues

Tags: wordpress

I have a site that is using PayPal Standard as their Payment Processor and WordPress as the CMS.   After the upgrade from 4.4.x to 4.5.8 Recurring Payments are no longer working.

Could this be related to issues where the PayPal IPN callback fails?  I suspect that the issue is that PayPal is not communicating properly with the site.  Where can we find the code that would handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this is working on my development site:

Code removed as the actual solution is now in CiviCRM v 4.6.3

The first part is gets the payment status to flip to completed, the second section lets the IPN call back complete and send the email.   This is by no means perfect as if wp-load.php is NOT in the doc root it will fail.

It is a working solution for now.  Will comment if a better more flexible solution can be found

Patches for this problem are documented here:  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629

CiviCRM version 4.6.3 for WordPress fixes the issue

Comment: Just wanted to note that a dynamic solution is proposed and I am hoping will be in version 4.6.3.  See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5751 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/75

Answer (score 3):

There's [a bug report](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629) that sounds like the same issue - it's because the WordPress wp-load.php file isn't getting bootstrapped properly in some circumstances. I had a similar problem and used [Brian Shaughnessy's fix](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629?focusedCommentId=70604&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-70604), which worked - but Kevin Cristiano [reported](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629?focusedCommentId=71849&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-71849) that he needed to also alter an IPN file.

I got fed up with counting relative directories, so my actual code in CRM_Core_Permission_WordPress was:

```
    if (!defined(ABSPATH) || !defined(WPINC)) {
      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
      $path .= "/wp-load.php";
      require_once($path); 
    }
```

Obviously alter the location as your setup requires...

Comment: wait - I just spotted that you *are* Kevin Cristiano :-) so presumably this fix wasn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think we have the same issue in Drupal CiviCRM 4.5.5. PayPal IPN history shows the notifications are being sent through, but nothing is being recorded or updated in CiviCRM.

Thesee are recurring contributions which were previously set-up successfully.

Comment: I've just spoken to PayPal today. If you have a recurring payment (or subscription) set up previously on an old domain you can't update the URL the IPN notifications are being sent to!

Only new payments will receive the IPN to the right URL.